# Gradle sourceDir not adding defaultRootSource for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, eclipse-wtp

I trying to configure **eclipse-wtp** to work with old Ant project. My web project is in `/app`. Everything almost works. The only missing part is tag `defaultRootSource` in `<wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/path/euro-gradle/app"/>`. When I add this tag (by editing *org.eclipse.wst.common.component*) applications starts normally on embedded Tomcat. Without this Tomcat just starts and not deploy application.

My gradle build:

```
eclipse {
    wtp {
        facet{
            facet name: 'jst.web', version: '2.5'
            facet name: 'java', version: '1.7'
        }

        component {
            contextPath = '/'
//            resource deployPath: '/', sourcePath: '/app'
            sourceDirs += file('/app')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to set `webAppDirName` on your project (which defaults to `src/main/webapp`). See also http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/war_plugin.html. `eclipse-wtp` plugin will use this path as the default root source path.

Comment: ```webAppDirName``` should be a ```String```, in your case: ```webAppDirName = '/app'```.
But if it compiles and runs without error, this shouldn't be the problem, which Gradle version do you use?

Comment: Hm ... I have re-written quite a lot of that code and I the corresponding test case as well my test works ... Can you paste your build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that the Gradle WbResource generator, used to create the deployment configuration file .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component, supports anything but deploy path and source path at the moment.

[WbResource source code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/6277a4dc70fbeea83c111e75c95ba851d1e56ffc/subprojects/ide/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/plugins/ide/eclipse/model/WbResource.groovy)

So we have to resort to direct xml manipulation:

```
eclipse.wtp.component.file.withXml { provider ->
    def mainWebSourcePathNode = provider.asNode()['wb-module'][0].get('wb-resource').find { 
        it.attribute('source-path') == project.convention.plugins.war.webAppDirName 
    }
    mainWebSourcePathNode['@tag'] = 'defaultRootSource'
}
```